# how to describe the location of line

Tags: figures-of-speech

is it possible that I can describe the location of a single line in the figure as following,

e.g. a line is located in +45 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**is it possible that I can describe the location of a single line in the figure as following,
e.g. a line is located in +45 degrees.**

The normal terminology would be "a line located **at** 45 degrees" (this means +45 degrees) but you would not normally say located at.

Example **the line** (drawn) **at** (an angle of) **45 degrees**

Alternatively **the line sloping down at 45 degrees** ( -45 degrees)

**at** preposition (PLACE) used to show an exact position or particular place.

**at** preposition (DIRECTION) in the direction of: [Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at)

Comment: Lines are typically infinitely long and are “located” using a point It passes ***through*** and a slope/direction or by two points It passes through.